# Getting error from create-strapi-starter during CRA init

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, strapi

I have a problem with CRA; after the command `yarn create react-app my-app` I get a strange error: `error create-strapi-starter@3.6.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got a "16.14.2" error Found an incompatible module. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.`
Why do I get this error with create-strapi-starter?

I've also removed create-strapi-starter from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: `yarn config set ignore-engines true` helped